# How do I remove the 'Whatsapp' button in Firefox's menu?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, firefox-for-android, share-menu

The big green button in the second row of the menu, shown in the image below. It does not appear as a Firefox addon, and Whatsapp itself doesn't seem to have any option regarding this.

[image: Firefox Screenshot]

<sub>Screenshot - Firefox (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

And how can I prevent stuff like this getting added to Firefox in the future? This seems to have the same potential for abuse as the desktop browsers' 'toolbars' system, and I wish to preemptively disable such changes to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp is the last app you used to share a link. 
To change it to something else, you need to share a link with another app, or if you want to remove any app icon from the menu, just uninstall and install the app again.

Comment: Is there a way I can disable this feature in Firefox entirely? The general share button in the first row's right is good enough for me, this 'last shared app' taking up an entire row is superfluous to me.

Comment: @sundar As much as I know, you cannot disable this option. It's on most of the apps, including gallery and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

That's the last application you shared with.
Share with another application or just ignore.